# App submission to Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I have few queries regarding Android app submission.

1) I have an account and want to make my application available for US.(I have seen the options which allows to select the countries in submission process document). So is it possible to show my application to US users with my india account.

2) I want to show the different names for Seller(developer) and copyrights. In future If I submit another app, I should be able to show the same seller name but copy rights name will be changed. So is it possible to show in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Malleswar

Answer (score 0):

1.) You should be able to make it available to US markets just fine, it might depend on where you live though. I'm not sure about india

2.) It depends where you want to display the developer. All apps you upload under one account will be shown on that account. You can place whatever you want in your short description though. I'm not sure there's a copyright section on the market though. You're free to link to any website you want from the store though, where you can place whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that case If I have one login id(developer id) and every time I want to change the developer id for each application. Is it possible.

Comment: No. You'd need to get different accounts